# Problem with getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, web-applications

I am writing an upload and a download function, and I try to have this two methods to write to or read from the same folder, and I ran into some problem with `getResourceAsStream`. (The software is run on glassfish)

**upload**: The method upload to this folder: `/home/phamtn8/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/Documents/Documents-war_war/drawings/Liandro.jpg` --> work great

**download**: stream = `the above path`

`input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(stream);`  //This return null

The location of the class files that contain these upload and download methods is at:
`/home/phamtn8/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/Documents/Documents-war_war/WEB-INF/classes/org/xdrawing/web`. If I put the `jpg` file here, the `getResourceAsStream` work.

NOTE: `this.getClass.getName()` return `org.xdrawing.web.FileName`

Please help !!!

Comment: Storing things into your classpath is a really weird and wrong thing to do. What happens if someone uploads a class file? It'll get added to your classpath! Best to store them in an area dedicated to storing files.

Comment: Thank you. Doing it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getResourceAsStream(..)` treats paths from the root of the classpath. And yours seems to be the root of the machine. So use `new FileInpuStream(fullPath)` instead.

In fact, there is another `getResourceAsStream` method that belongs to the `ServletContext`. It treats paths from the root of the web application, and is more suitable for web applications. (your web app root is `Documents-war_war/`)

But the best practice with file uploads and downloads is to store them in a totally different location from your web application - say `/home/appname/uploads`, so that you can deploy and undeploy the web-app without losing any data. You will just need a configuration option (a `<context-param>` in `web.xml` for example) that points to the absolute location of the uploads, and use the `FileInputStream` approach (or `OutputStream` respectively)